# How to create an instance just by generic type T

Tags: java, generics

I want to create an instance just by defining the type for a generic class

```
public abstract class Base<T> {
    private final T genericTypeObject;

    protected Base(){
          //Create instance of T here without any argument

    }
}
```

So that I just can call the default constructor:

```
public class Child extends Base<SomeClass>{
    public Child () {
        super();
    }
}
```

and the Base-class implementation will create me an instance of the GenericType.

Comment: You may be asking an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and so yu may be better off explaining your overall problem and not how you're trying to (incorrectly) solve it.

Comment: Do you want a "clean" solution, or would you be happy with a dirty, reflection-based hack? I was trying to do something like that once, I've given up, but lately I think I've figured it out - though it's really hacky. If that suits you, I can try to finally do that.

Comment: Maybe you can provide me just both :D I kept the question simple for others . I will decide afterwards which fits best :D

Comment: Here's the dirty answer: 
Class<T> s;
    public Child(Class<T> s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    private T getInstance() {
        return s.newInstance();
    }

Comment: for a cleaner one, post details about the problem that you are trying to solve

Comment: I thought of something like: 

Class<T> clazz =  (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass()
                .getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels i am not sure if incorrect code does actually exist. Bad programmed one for sure. But if it works and fits the needs it's not incorrect.

Comment: _"Without any arguments"_ Why do you have that requirement? Passing an instance of `T` to the super constructor is by far the cleanest solution I can think of.

Comment: Engineering == Trying new ways!

Comment: See also: [Why can't you create an instance of a generic type using “new” operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30646486/why-cant-you-create-an-instance-of-a-generic-type-using-new-operator)

Comment: This has nothing to do with the marked question.

Comment: Well, you've figured it out yourself. I was thinking about private inner interface with single parameterless method returning T, then analyzing type returned from that method with reflection to obtain Class<T> without passing it to the constructor. Once you have instance of Class<T> Bob's your uncle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The generic information will be **erased at compile time**, so there will be no `T` anymore **during runtime** (you loose the information). Thats why you somewhere will need a `Class<>` to store the information.

---

The most clean & simple solution form my point of view is to pass in the class to to the constructor. I know you requested it to be without any constructor argument, but I do not think this is possible.

---

#### Code Sample

```
public abstract class AbstractBase<T> {

    private final T genericTypeObject;

    protected Base(Class<T> type){
        try {
            genericTypeObject = type.newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            // Handle
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // Handle
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Child extends Base<SomeClass> {

    public Child () {
        super(SomeClass.class);
    }
}
```

#### Alternative Solution

Using a `Supplier` (thanks for the comment @Jorn Vernee):

```
public abstract class AbstractBase<T> {

  private final T genericTypeObject;

  public AbstractBase(Supplier<T> supplier) {
    genericTypeObject = supplier.get();
  }
}
```

---

```
public class Child extends AbstractBase<SomeClass> {

  public Child() {
    super(SomeClass::new);
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of this, I would suggest passing a constructor [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/91/lambda-expressions/5080), since it doesn't throw any exceptions.

Comment: Thank you, added your suggestion.

Comment: The erasing part may be right in the case i do not have a class, wehere the generic type is extended from something. Maybe my questionw as to simplified.

Answer (score 0):

You must have access to the class to create an instance, so creating an instance without an argument is not possible. You must pass a `Class<T>`.

UPDATE:

See @JDC's answer.

Answer (score 0):

At runtime this returns me a Class instance:

```
public static Class<?> getGenericClassOfType(Object object){
        Class<?> clazz = (Class<?>) ((ParameterizedType) object.getClass() .getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        return clazz;
}
```

and afterwards I can initiate it with:

```
public static <T> T getDefaultInstance(Class<T> clazz) throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException {
    T instance = null;
    Constructor<T>[] constructors = (Constructor<T>[]) clazz.getDeclaredConstructors();
    Constructor<T> constructor = null;
    for (Constructor cstr : constructors) {
        //Only if default constructor
        if (cstr.getParameters().length == 0) {
            constructor = (Constructor<T>) cstr;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (constructor != null) {
        constructor.setAccessible(true);
        instance = constructor.newInstance();
    }

    return instance;
}
```

so the code in my base constructor looks like:

```
public abstract class BaseScene<T extends SceneController> {
    private final static Logger LOGGER =  LogManager.getLogger(BaseScene.class);

    private final T sceneController;

    //public T getSceneController() {
    //    return sceneController;
    //}

    protected BaseScene(){
        T newInstance = null;
        try {
            Class<T> clazz = (Class<T>)ReflectionHelper.getGenericClassOfType(this);
            newInstance = ReflectionHelper.getDefaultInstance(clazz);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | InstantiationException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error while trying to initiate BaseScene",e);
        }
        sceneController = newInstance;
    }
}
```

which works perfectly as I tested it.